# How can I convert this semidefinite program into standard form?

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}$Consider the following semidefinite program (SDP)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_V \quad & \Tr(V) \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & AVB + CVD + Q \succeq 0 \\
\quad & V \succeq 0
\end{aligned} \tag{1}
$$
where $V \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}, A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}, B \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}, C \in \mathbb R^{m \times n},D \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$, and $Q \in \mathbb R^{m \times m} \succeq 0$. The solution to this problem is trivial, but this is a minimal example of a larger and more complex problem that I have a question about. More specifically, how can I convert the problem in $(1)$ into the following equivalent standard form of an SDP?
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_x \quad & c^Tx \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & F_0 + x_1F_1 + \cdots + x_mF_m \succeq 0
\end{aligned} \tag{2}
$$
where $F_0,\dots,F_m$ are symmetric matrices, $c \in \mathbb R^m$, and $x \in \mathbb R^m$. That is, how can I relate $x, c,$ and the matrices $F_0,\dots,F_m$ in $(2)$ to the matrices $V, A, B, C, D,$ and $Q$ given in $(1)$? The reason I'm interested in this conversion is that the standard form in $(2)$ is more amenable to further analysis than the form given in $(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}$We transform the problem in $(1)$ into the problem in $(2)$ as follows. First, for $(i,j) \in \{(k,\ell) \mid (k,\ell) \in \{1,\dots,n\}^2, k \leq \ell\}$, let $E_{ij} \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be the matrix with a $1$ in the $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ positions and $0$'s everywhere else. When $i = j$, $E_{ii}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $(i,i)$ position and $0$'s everywhere else. For example, when $n = 2$, we have the following 3 matrices
$$
\begin{align}
E_{11} &= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \\
E_{12} &= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \\
E_{22} &= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Note that these 3 matrices form a basis for the vector space of $2 \times 2$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrices. More generally, for arbitrary $n$, the $n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ matrices $E_{11},E_{12},\dots,E_{1n},E_{22},E_{23},\dots,E_{2n},\dots,E_{(n-1)(n-1)},E_{(n-1)n},E_{nn}$ form a basis for the vector space of $n \times n$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrices. Therefore, every $V \succeq 0 \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ can be decomposed as
$$
\begin{align}
V &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}E_{ij} \tag{3} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n v_{1j}E_{1j} + \sum_{j=2}^n v_{2j}E_{2j} + \cdots + \sum_{j=n-1}^n v_{(n-1)j}E_{(n-1)j} + \sum_{j=n}^n v_{nj}E_{nj}
\end{align}
$$
where $v_{ij}$ is the element of $V$ in the $(i,j)$ position. We first substitute this expression for $V$ into the objective function in $(1)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\Tr(V) &= \Tr\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}E_{ij}\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}\Tr\left(E_{ij}\right) \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Note that, when $i \neq j$, $\Tr(E_{ij}) = 0$, and when $i = j$, $\Tr(E_{ij}) = 1$. So, the expression in $(4)$ above simplifies to
$$
\begin{align}
\Tr(V) &= \sum_{i=1}^n v_{ii}\Tr\left(E_{ii}\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n v_{ii}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, to relate the objective function in the problem in $(1)$ to the objective function in the problem in $(2)$, we let
$$
\begin{align}
x = \begin{bmatrix}v_{11} \\ v_{12} \\ \vdots \\ v_{1n} \\ v_{22} \\ v_{23} \\ \vdots \\ v_{2n} \\ \vdots \\ v_{(n-1)(n-1)} \\ v_{(n-1)n} \\ v_{nn}\end{bmatrix}, \quad c = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Note that $x \in \mathbb R^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ and $c \in \mathbb R^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$. Next, we relate the constraints in the problem in $(1)$ to the constraint in the problem in $(2)$ as follows. We substitute the expression for $V$ given in $(3)$ into the first constraint in $(1)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
AVB + CVD + Q &\succeq 0 \\
A\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}E_{ij}\right)B + C\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}E_{ij}\right)D + Q &\succeq 0 \\
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}AE_{ij}B\right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}CE_{ij}D\right) + Q &\succeq 0 \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}\left(AE_{ij}B + CE_{ij}D\right) + Q &\succeq 0 \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, we apply this process to the second constraint in $(1)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
V &\succeq 0 \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}E_{ij} &\succeq 0 \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
We can combine the constraints in $(5)$ and $(6)$ together into one constraint as follows.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}\left(AE_{ij}B + CE_{ij}D\right) + Q \succeq 0 \  \wedge \ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}E_{ij} \succeq 0 &\iff \begin{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}\left(AE_{ij}B + CE_{ij}D\right) + Q & 0 \\ 0 & \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij}E_{ij} \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
&\iff \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij} \begin{bmatrix}AE_{ij}B + CE_{ij}D & 0 \\ 0 & E_{ij} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}Q & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
We then let
$$
F_0 = \begin{bmatrix}Q & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and for $(i,j) \in \{(k,\ell) \mid (k,\ell) \in \{1,\dots,n\}^2, k \leq \ell\}$, we let
$$
F_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}AE_{ij}B + CE_{ij}D & 0 \\ 0 & E_{ij} \end{bmatrix}
$$
such that the constraint in $(7)$ becomes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n v_{ij} F_{ij} + F_0 \succeq 0
$$
as desired.

---

The decomposition of $V$ into its constituent basis matrices was adapted from section 2.1.2, titled "Linear equality constraints", in the book

> S. Boyd, L. El Ghaoui, E. Feron, and V. Balakrishnan, Linear matrix inequalities in system and control theory. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 1994. doi: 10.1137/1.9781611970777.

A similar decomposition can be found in remark 1.24 in section 1.4.1 in the lecture notes titled "Linear Matrix Inequalities in Control" by Carsten Scherer and Siep Weiland (2015) (available [here](https://www.imng.uni-stuttgart.de/mst/files/LectureNotes.pdf)).